# How does the swift .contains(element:_) method work?

Tags: swift, search, contains

When you search for an element in an array you can use the `.contains()` method. What I would like to know is how it works, does it do a **binary search** or a **sequential search** or something else entirely?

Comment: That should be considered as an implementation detail, but as it works with arbitrary (not necessarily sorted) arrays, a binary search cannot be used. If you are really curious, look it up in the Swift source code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains(_:)` method is defined on (and provided by protocol extensions to) `Sequence`. A `Sequence` makes no assumptions about the stability of its content and doesn't provide random access, so it *cant* do more than a linear search. A `Collection` provides random access, so it's at least possible to implement binary search on one, but for that to happen you'd need a guarantee that the contents are sorted.

That there's a [proposal for adding binary search to the Swift Standard Library](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0074-binary-search.md#rationale) is another good sign that there isn't a binary search method already.

You can, however, cast an `Array` (whose contents are sorted) to `NSArray` and use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1412722-indexofobject) for a binary search.